# Method $this->__('');

Tags: magento-1.9

I can't understand, why I can't write just `echo "Agent"`, but I can write `echo $this->__('Agent');`? And what does this method do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write `echo "Agent"` but you shouldn't write it, `echo $this->__('Agent');` is right (*recommended*) as per Magento standards.

While you use `echo $this->__('Agent');`, you can translate `Agent` word to any other language (*when you have multiple stores*) by simply adding it to language translate csv. A simple echo will print same word for all stores.

Answer (score 3):

You can write `echo "Agent"` but when you write `echo $this->__('Agent')` you can use the same word for translation.

When the **__()** method is called, Magento first looks for a translation in array matching the current module.
The current module is determined by the class name on which the __() class is called.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, these methods translate the phrase. Using direct echo call may lead to issues for multi-language sites